# How did Thanos rewind Vision?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

How did Thanos rewind the Infinity Stone in Vision at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*? The stone is 1/6 of a Goddess and Doctor Strange can't even rewind a semi magic Book with 'Consequences'. It doesn't really make sense to me unless this will be a key plot point in *Endgame*.

[image: Thanos uses the time stone slotted on the gauntlet]
[image: Doctor Strange uses the time stone]

Comment: Not clear what you mean.. he didn't "rewind the Mind Stone"... he rewound the timeline and all events that happened; which happened to include the destruction of the Mind Stone. It doesn't seem any different than what Strange did to undo the destruction of the Hong Kong Sanctum.

Comment: What I mean is he basically Reverse Uno’d the Mind Stones Destruction and the Sanctum isn’t a Magical Object

Comment: He more or less traveled back in time; he went to a time before it had been destroyed. I don't see any reason to think that an artifact, no matter how magical or special or powerful, would somehow still remain broken after travelling back to a time before it was broken.

Comment: keep in mind that Strange is an inexperienced Sorcerer using the Time Stone through it's container. Thanos not only is not only using the stone itself but he knows how to use them as he's used the Reality Stone on all of Knowhere, he knew right away how to use the Space Stone to open portals don't forget that in a flight he blew up a moon and has it's fragments rain down as meteors

Answer (score 1):

The key is to remember the scene with the apple in the Dr. Strange movie.

If you recall, Dr. Strange uses the Time Stone to reverse and advance the age of the apple, from half eaten to uneaten to rotting.

This shows that the Time Stone can specifically target an object, which is what Thanos did to Vision.